# String of decimal numbers to byte array [c#]

Tags: c#, string, arrays, biginteger

I have problem in c# with convert decimal number from string to byte array. I want creat BigInteger with using byte array.

I try:

```
string Astr = "123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789";
byte[] AByte = Astr.Select(c => (byte)(c - '0')).ToArray(); //This is problem because array padding wrong.
```

Tnaks for your ideas. :)

Comment: So one *idea*: a single decimal digit **does not** occupy one full byte.

Comment: I don't understand your question clearly but `BigInteger` structure has an [Byte array constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268207%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Did you tried it? _Note_: It is not a CLS compliant.

Comment: BigInteger in c# is small - I need work with cca 2048 bit numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to create the BigInteger from a byte array when you have the string available?

Why not just do this?

```
string aStr = "123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789";
BigInteger x = BigInteger.Parse(aStr);
```

Also note that there is no easy correspondence between a BigInteger in string form and its byte array.

For example, following on from the code above, if you add this:

```
var ba = x.ToByteArray();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", ba.Select(v => v.ToString("x"))));
```

The output is:

```
15 5f 4 84 b6 70 28 c7 73 7b a3 d5 f9 b a1 8 67 12 b0 a5 af 52 ba cb e4 66 6c 75 78 66 92 31 2a 4
```

Which is the byte[] version of the original string after being encoded as a BigInteger.

Comment: BigInteger in c# is small for me :( - I need work with cca 2048 bit numbers.

Comment: @user3299032 But C# integer works with 2048 bit numbers (and much more), so what is your actual problem?